# hartl chapter 5 Heroku errors

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've seen a similar issue posted before but it doesn't address my particular problem.   I have finished chapter 5 of Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial while its been great so far, I am currently having a weird issue.   After having tested the app locally(and found everything to be working as expected) I pushed the app to Heroku.  Now when I click on the About or Contact page links in the footer of the pages on Heroku, I get a message saying "We've encountered a problem".   All other links work and I 've checked the footer partial file, it seems fine.

The logs don't seem to be telling me anything useful.  I will post the log file, the footer, the Gemfile, and the routes.   Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Routes

```
SampleApp::Application.routes.draw do
  get "users/new"

  root  to: 'static_pages#home' 



  match '/signup', to: 'users#new'

  match '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#About'
  match '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'

end
```

footer partial

```
<footer class="footer">
<small>
    <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Rails Tutorial</a>
    by Michael Hartl
</small>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %></li>
        <li><a href="http://news.railstutorial.org/">News</a>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</footer>
```

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '1.9.3'

gem 'rails', '3.2.12'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
group :development, :test do

gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
gem 'rspec-rails', '2.11.0'
end 

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails', '3.2.5'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
    gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
end


gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'

group :test do
gem 'capybara', '1.1.2'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg', '0.12.2'
end
```

LOGS (Update:  I have a new set of logs and it seems that its claiming theres a missing template, which is not missing)  I still don't understand whats happening.

```
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516275+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template static_pages/about, application/about with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder]}. Searched in:
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516275+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516275+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/path_set.rb:58:in `find'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516275+00:00 app[web.1]:   * "/app/app/views"
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516275+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:109:in `find'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516275+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:3:in `find_template'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516531+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:110:in `_render_template'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516275+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:36:in `render_template'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516531+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:17:in `render'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516275+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:34:in `determine_template'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516275+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:10:in `render'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516531+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/compatibility.rb:50:in `render_to_body'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516531+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:225:in `_render_template'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516531+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516531+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:103:in `render_to_body'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516531+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:28:in `render_to_body'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516531+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:88:in `render'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516531+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block (2 levels) in render'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516766+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516531+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `block in ms'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516766+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295:in `realtime'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516766+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:5:in `ms'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516766+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `block in render'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516766+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:83:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516766+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.12/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:24:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516766+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516766+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:39:in `render'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516766+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516766+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516989+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516989+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__2984696832344586189__process_action__1371554362507721148__callbacks'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516989+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516989+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516989+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516989+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516989+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.516989+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.12/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
2013-05-03T16:31:41.517214+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
```

Again, everything works locally so i don't understand what could be going wrong.  I do see that it seems to be looking in app/app/views  which I also don't understand.   Any help from someone more experienced would be really appreciated.

EDIT:

Contents of contact.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, 'Contact Us') %>

<h1>Contact Us</h1>
<p>
  The <a href="http://railstutorial.org/">Ruby on Rails Tutorial</a>
  is a project to make a book and screencasts to teach web development
  with <a href="http://rubyonrails.org/">Ruby on Rails</a>. This
  is the sample application for the tutorial.
</p>
```

Contents of static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end

end
```

Comment: IT has now been a full day of trying to work this issue  out on my own and trying MANY different "solutions" I've found on this site, none of which do anything to help me out of this problem.  PLEASE HELP, anyone with some insight to why this is happening.   All files have been pushed to heroku and it works locally so I'm at a complete loss as to what is happening

Comment: can you post these files:
app/views/static_pages/about.html.erb
app/views/static_pages/contact.html.erb
app/controllers/static_pages_controller.rb

Comment: Yes.  Fortunately I resolved the issue with the about page but still over a month later cannot resolve the contact page issue.  I will post both contact.html.erb and the static_pages_controller.rb files when I get home.

Comment: To fix the about page I had to change the route to match the file name (which I had accidentally capitalized when creating it).  But that is not the issue with the contact page so I'm at a loss.  And I have no worked up through ch 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you didn't already get it working, make sure you've staged all files to be pushed with `git` (maybe use `git add .`) and then commit (`git commit -m "foo") then push to Heroku.

Comment: Note that `git -A :/` will add all files in the repo (exc. those in `.gitignore`). A common newbie issue is doing `git add .` in a nested directory and not including updated files elsewhere in the directory structure.

Comment: if you do `git add .` do it from the root of the application.

Comment: Thanks, I checked on it and I have added all files to my git repo so I do not think that is the issue.  I even specifically tried to add the files giving me issues and nothing changed.